Unable to create GPU_IVF_PQ index
so I deploy a milvus cluster 2.4 to awk eks, and was hoping to try out gpu indices. however when I try to create gpu index on a tiny collection I got something like
[2024/06/04 12:37:05.472 +00:00] [INFO] [indexnode/task.go:516] ["index params are ready"] [buildID=450232097587185780] ["index params"="{\"cache_dataset_on_device\":\"false\",\"dim\":\"768\",\"index_type\":\"GPU_IVF_PQ\",\"m\":\"16\",\"metric_type\":\"IP\",\"nbits\":\"8\",\"nlist\":\"2048\"}"]
E20240604 12:37:05.594095    45 index_factory.cc:49] [KNOWHERE][Create][milvus] failed to find index GPU_IVF_PQ_fp32 in factory
[2024/06/04 12:37:05.595 +00:00] [WARN] [indexcgowrapper/helper.go:71] ["failed to create index, C Runtime Exception: index not supported\n"]

milvus version is milvusdb/milvus:v2.4.3
deployed to an awk eks cluster
I don't see any gpu specific config except for
gpu:
initMemSize: 0
maxMemSize: 0
the gpu nodes are g5.2xlarge, driver version 550.54.15
nvidia-smi
Wed Jun  5 08:11:43 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.15              Driver Version: 550.54.15      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A10G                    On  |   00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   20C    P8             12W /  300W |       0MiB /  23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

so wondering what am I missing?

you have to use GPU  docker image.
see document here https://milvus.io/docs/install_cluster-helm-gpu.md

This should work
# Set up the index parameters
index_params = {
    "metric_type": "L2",
    "index_type": "GPU_IVF_PQ",
    "params": {
        "nlist": 1024,
        "m": 4,
        "nbits": 8
    }
}

# Create the index
client.create_index(
    collection_name="example_collection",
    field_name="vector_field",
    index_params=index_params
)

